# How to make typescript evaluate a fat arrow function explicitly?

Tags: angular, typescript, lambda, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am using a `FormBuilder` in a angular form.I want to initialize the value of the `FormControl` based on the response received from a API call to backend (referred as `userFormDetails` here).

I am trying to use fat arrow function `()=>` for the same like :

```
//Other Form Controls
 empCode:[this.userFormDetails.userId],
 empName:[this.userFormDetails.name],
 pensionType:[''],
 fhName:[
          ()=>{
return this.userFormDetails.gender=="Male"? this.userFormDetails.fatherName:this.userFormDetails.spouseName
}],   
.
//Rest of the controls
```

However this get evaluated as

`function () {                    return _this.userFormDetails.gender == "Male" ? _this.userFormDetails.fatherName : _this.userFormDetails.spouseName;                }`

It returns the function itself as the value instead of evaluating it. How can I make the function return the evaluated value?

I also tried doing:

1.

```
()=>{ ( **<--addition parenthesis**
return this.userFormDetails.gender=="Male"? this.userFormDetails.fatherName:this.userFormDetails.spouseName
)}
```

2. Setting value of FormControl as:

```
fhName:[{
     value: ()=>{
                 return this.userFormDetails.gender=="Male"? 
                 this.userFormDetails.fatherName:this.userFormDetails.spouseName
                },
                disabled:false
             }
            ]
```

But none of them worked.
Can someone guide me the correct method to do this?

Comment: did you try this way ? (() => { */ content /* })()

Comment: Am I right, that you want to set a specific value to the `fhName` control depending on a condition.

Comment: Can't you just `fhName:[this.userFormDetails.gender==='Male'?this.userFormDetails.fatherName:this.userFormDetails.spouseName],`

Comment: @JithinScaria it works perfectly fine!! Thanks !. If possible can you explain why wrapping this fat arrow function in parenthesis and then calling it works?

Comment: @Batajus Yes you are correct

Comment: @Fussel yes that would work surely , but I was just trying to play around with anonymous functions in TS and see how this can be achieved with it. Anyways thanks dear! :)

Comment: @SrajanSoni , its using an anonymous function as a closure. Added a link and solution as an answer below for your reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the form control equal to function. you have declared it but you are not calling it, so use as a anonymous function as a closure, like below.

try changing this way,

```
fhName:[(()=>{
return this.userFormDetails.gender=="Male"? this.userFormDetails.fatherName:this.userFormDetails.spouseName
})()]
```

Additional `()` at the end of funtion wrapped inside `()` will declare and call the function.

see more about [anonymous function](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/JavaScript/Anonymous_functions)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Jithin Scaria in the comments, the following method works :

`(() => { / content / })()`
Wrapping the function in parenthesis and then calling it makes TS to compute the value and return it.